# Merging a single key array to a value array

Tags: json, object, jq, reshape

My original json:

```js
{
   columns:["colA","colB","colC"]
   values: [
       ["3","abc",200],
       ["4","def",300],
       ["5","ghi",400],
       ["6","jkl",500]
   ]

}
```

I want to produce:

```js
[
    {colA: 3, colB: "abc", colC: 200},
    {colA: 4, colB: "def", colC: 300},
    {colA: 5, colB: "ghi", colC: 400},
    {colA: 6, colB: "jkl", colC: 500}
]
```

I cannot seem to find the correct way to do it if possible at all.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#zip-column-headers-with-their-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input is not quite valid JSON, but once it's fixed, you can use `def objectify` from the jq Cookbook (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook):

```
# objectify/1 expects an array of atomic values as inputs, and packages
# these into an object with keys specified by the "headers" array and
# values obtained by trimming string values, replacing empty strings
# by null, and converting strings to numbers if possible.
def objectify(headers):
  def tonumberq: tonumber? // .;
  def trimq: if type == "string" then sub("^ +";"") | sub(" +$";"") else . end;
  def tonullq: if . == "" then null else . end;
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; headers|length) as $i
      ({}; .[headers[$i]] = ($in[$i] | trimq | tonumberq | tonullq) );
```

With this def, the "main" jq filter is simply:

```
.columns as $headers
| .values
| map(objectify($headers))
```